# URL configuration issue with Django app using Bluehost

Tags: django, apache, .htaccess, fastcgi, bluehost

I'm in the process of deploying my Django app to a production server using Bluehost but keep seeing my site's 404 page. The issue seems to be my URL configuration. When I type http://www.example.com/ into my browser I receive the following :

```
Request URL:    http://www.example.com/public_html/

^main/
^admin/
^accounts/
^media/(?P<path>.*)$
etc..

The current URL, public_html/, didn't match any of these
```

public_html/ is automatically added to the end of my URL I would like to eliminate the public_html/ entirely so my URL pattern will work as expected. For example

```
Request URL:    http://www.example.com/
```

Which would then redirect to

```
Request URL:    http://www.example.com/main/
```

How would I go about changing the default from http://www.example.com/public_html/ to http://www.example.com/ ?

My fcgi file:

```
AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(media/.*)$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(adminmedia/.*)$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(cgi-bin/mysite.fcgi)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ cgi-bin/mysite.fcgi/$1 [L]
```

My .htaccess file:

```
#!/home/username/python/bin/python
import sys, os

sys.path.insert(0, "/home/username/python")
sys.path.insert(13, "/home/username/MySite")

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'MySite.settings'

from django.core.servers.fastcgi import runfastcgi

runfastcgi(method="threaded", daemonize="false")
```

Is there a possibility this could be an issue with where my files are located on my server?  If anyone has experienced this kind of issue before I would greatly appreciate some advice.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have to define following url in your urls.py,

```
url(r'^$', 'views.home', name='home')
url(r'^main/$', 'views.main', name='main')
```

then in views.py

```
def home(request):
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/main/')

def main(request):
    #some code here.
```

Comment: Thanks for the response!  This works great for solving the second part of the problem.  Typing in my main URL now redirects to the main page exactly as I would like it to.  However on my production server the same problem still happens.  When I type www.example.com  into my browser i still receive the same error: 
(The current URL, public_html/, didn't match any of these). Public_html is still being appended to the end of my URL and causing all of my URLs to have issues

Comment: In your production server, may be there is another default urls.py containing public_html in your hosting server. Check it.

or set root url in your settings.py

Comment: I tried both of your suggestions and unfortunately neither of them worked.  The only urls.py files are those within my project and it is working as expected. Actually my my current django configuration works perfectly when using my dev server.  The public_html/ issue only happens on my production server.  And I can't for the life of my figure out what is causing public_html/ to be appended to my URL